# How to check whether an external display is ON or OFF in Python?

Tags: python, macos, external-display

I have a Mac Mini that is connected to a single, external display via HDMI. It is a third-party display (made by Dell); the "change brightness" function keys on the Apple keyboard have no effect the display.

The display ON/OFF state is toggled simply by manually pressing the power button on the face of the display.

I am looking for Python code that checks whether this display is ON or OFF. I am open to a command-line-based solution.

Note that the display remains connected to the computer whether the display is ON or OFF. Consequently, the [Display Manager library](https://github.com/univ-of-utah-marriott-library-apple/display_manager) cannot help me here.

The context is that I want a Python script to only play some audio when the display is turned OFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099333/terminal-command-to-show-connected-displays-monitors-resolutions) you can check the specifications of attached monitors on MacOS with the following command:

```
$ system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

This will return information such as :

```
Graphics/Displays:

    NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M:

      Chipset Model: NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M
      Type: GPU
      Bus: PCIe
      PCIe Lane Width: x16
      VRAM (Total): 512 MB
      Vendor: NVIDIA (0x10de)
      Device ID: 0x0fd8
      Revision ID: 0x00a2
      ROM Revision: 3707
      Displays:
        iMac:
          Display Type: LCD
          Resolution: 1920 x 1080
          Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
          Main Display: Yes
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Built-In: Yes
          Connection Type: DisplayPort
```

My assumption is that when no display is connected, there will be no strings for `Display Type`, `Resolution` or the others.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output) is more info on running a command line program in Python with command line arguments, and receiving the output, i.e. :

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> result = subprocess.run(['system_profiler', 'SPDisplaysDataType'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> result.stdout
```

And result.stdout will contain the string returned (something like shown previously). Then you can search the returned string for which ever parameters you want maybe:

```
if "Display Type" not in result.stdout: 
    screenConnected = false
    playMusic()
```

Obviously its worth checking other parameters and adding some error handling, but maybe this is a place to start.

I'm not sure if there could be a callback approach to this / haven't found any Python libraries myself, but please comment any in my answer and I will update.

Let me know if this works!