# Reading serial number of external monitor connected to M2 MacBook

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, monitor

How can I read serial number of a connected external monitor to a M2 Mac book pro programatically or using any terminal commands.

"system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep "Serial Number" -B5" fails to get serial.

ioreg -lw0 | grep -i "DisplayAttributes"

display attributes seems empty.

and "AppleCLCD2" is also missing in ioreg -lw0.

is there any other terminal command to read serial number of the connected external displays (with M2 Macbook).

Comment: Maybe this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65674921/2227743

Comment: no, we will not get the serial of external displays using these commands on M1 or M2 Mac